# How do i select the first division of a certain class?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, data-collection

I'm using selenium for web scraping. I'm trying to scrape the content of a paragraph within a division of a certain class X. The problem im having is that there are multiple `div` with the same `class` inside a collapse group, and what i wanna do is take only the first `div` of this `class` within each collapse group.
so for example when i run this piece of code:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='X']//p[1])
```

what happens is that i get all first paragraphs from all divisions containing with the `class X`. so im having for each collapse group multiple paragraphs. is there a way i can index the division?
maybe something like:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[1][@class='X']//p[1])
# or 
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='X'][1]//p[1])
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: try using `//div[first()]`